# Why is $\tan 54^\circ\approx \frac{\sin24^\circ}{1-\sqrt{3}\sin24^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

This question was asked as an equality on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889971/prove-tan-54-circ-frac-sin24-circ1-sqrt3-sin24-circ) and I am quite surprised to find that its  [strictly false](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is%20tan54%3D%28sin24%29%2F%281-sqrt%7B3%7D%28sin24%29%29%3F)

However I would like to see why is their difference of the order $10^{-15}$?

> $$\tan 54^\circ\approx \dfrac{\sin24^\circ}{1-\sqrt{3}\sin24^\circ}$$

Comment: If you ask Wolfram Alpha for an explicit form for $\tan\left(\frac{3\pi}{10}\right)$ it gives $\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}}$.  If you ask it what $\frac{\sin(\frac{2\pi}{15})}{1-\sqrt{3}\sin(\frac{2\pi}{15})}$ is, it will give $\sqrt{\frac15(5+2\sqrt{5})}$ as an exact form.  It just can't figure out they're equal through all the conversions, I suspect.

Comment: Mathematica uses (normally) floating point accuracy in the calculations, which is roughly $10^{-15}$. One can increase the accuracy by using: '  SetAccuracy[expression,n] '  where $n$ is the number of digits needed. Applying this to the equation above and taking $n=30$ gives $0$ (to an accuracy of $10^{-30}$).

Comment: I have posted a correct complete proof to the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prove $\tan 54^\circ=\frac{\sin24^\circ}{1-\sqrt{3}\sin24^\circ}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889971/prove-tan-54-circ-frac-sin24-circ1-sqrt3-sin24-circ)

Comment: @Thomas The OP links to your alleged duplicate in their post - they are asking about the accuracy of the approximation, and why it is what it is. "If they are equal, then why is Wolfram-Alpha saying otherwise?"

Answer (score 2):

$\tan 54^\circ\color{red}{=} \frac{\sin24^\circ}{1-\sqrt{3}\sin24^\circ}$ is true as darth geek [proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889971/prove-tan-54-circ-frac-sin24-circ1-sqrt3-sin24-circ#889976) analytically. The difference of $10^{-15}$ is a [numerical error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_error).

EDIT: One can prove this directly by using the exact values of [sine](http://intmstat.com/blog/2011/06/exact-values-sin-degrees.pdf), cosine and tangent.

Comment: If you mean that it is true then prove it and not just say so! Edit: That is much better, +1!

Comment: Why doesn't Wolfram does say so??

Comment: @metacompactness I ashall accept your answer if you prove the identity, for bonus :)

Comment: @metacompatness Can you complete it...

Comment: great lets see the proof.